# Use erlang as/instead of expect script

Tags: scripting, erlang

I would like to reset passwords on a bunch of boxes over SSH. Any pointers on how Erlang could be used for this purpose?

Comment: First step: decide why it is you want to use Erlang to do this instead of e.g. bash/perl/python.  Once you've identified the features that you specifically want to use, it will be much easier to come up with a solution that takes advatange of them.

Comment: Why Erlang? Firstly there is a large number of machines where I need to keep passwords in sync. So it would have been nice to run a number of tasks in parallel. Secondly I wanted to take advantage of pattern matching in Erlang. Existing tools such as fabric fail short to do anything more complicated than a simple pw-less login or simple password authentication. I also had more complicated scenarios - expired passwords, prompts for new passwords, retyping, retries, etc ... Thirdly I have a mix of machines with subtle differences in PW management ... Granted Erlang may be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang is indeed a well-suited choice for this problem.

You should have a look at the [ssh module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html). Start a connection with

```
ssh:connect(Host, Port, Options).
```

Then use the [ssh_connection module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh_connection.html) to execute the right `passwd` command (hint: start a shell first) and log out.

Edit: The above is mostly wrong, [this blog post might get you started faster.](http://easyerl.blogspot.com/2007/11/experimenting-with-erlang-ssh-support.html)

You can even write a simple server that does all of these things on several hosts in parallel, resulting in the most multicore-capable multi-host ssh password changer on this very planet. Weekend project idea: make a web app out of it.

Comment: I just hope he doesn't have to deal with public keys protected by a password, since they are not handled by the entire ssh application (unless the OTP team recently introduced it)...

Comment: Well, unfortunately I need to cover for the cases like: password-expired-pls-provide-new-validate-re-login hence the whole "expect" question.

Comment: once you're connected, you can do pretty much anything.

Answer (score -2):

***Simply don't use Erlang for such a thing.***

Reading from [here](http://www.erlang.org/faq/introduction.html):

> **What sort of applications is Erlang particularly suitable for?**
>
> - Distributed, reliable, soft real-time concurrent systems.
> - Telecommunication systems, e.g. controlling a switch or converting
>     protocols.
> - Servers for Internet applications, e.g. a mail transfer agent, an IMAP-4
>     server, an HTTP server or a WAP Stack.
> - Telecommunication applications, e.g. handling mobility in a mobile network
>     or providing unified messaging.
> - Database applications which require soft realtime behaviour.
> - Erlang is good at solving these sorts of problems because this is the
>     problem domain it was originally
>     designed for. Stating the above in
>     terms of features:
>
> Erlang provides a simple and powerful
>   model for error containment and fault
>   tolerance (supervised processes).
>
> - Concurrency and message passing are a fundamental to the language.
>     Applications written in Erlang are
>     often composed of hundreds or
>     thousands of lightweight processes.
>     Context switching between Erlang
>     processes is typically one or two
>     orders of magnitude cheaper than
>     switching between threads in a C
>     program.
> - Writing applications which are made of parts which execute on different
>     machines (i.e. distributed
>     applications) is easy. Erlang's
>     distribution mechanisms are
>     transparent: programs need not be
>     aware that they are distributed.
> - The OTP libraries provide support for many common problems in networking
>     and telecommunications systems.
> - The Erlang runtime environment (a virtual machine, much like the Java
>     virtual machine) means that code
>     compiled on one architecture runs
>     anywhere. The runtime system also
>     allows code in a running system to be
>     updated without interrupting the
>     program.
>
> **What sort of problems is Erlang not particularly suitable for?**
>
> People use Erlang for all sorts of
>   surprising things, for instance to
>   communicate with X11 at the protocol
>   level, but, there are some common
>   situations where Erlang is not likely
>   to be the language of choice.
>
> The most common class of 'less
>   suitable' problems is characterised by
>   performance being a prime requirement
>   and constant-factors having a large
>   effect on performance. Typical
>   examples are image processing, signal
>   processing, sorting large volumes of
>   data and low-level protocol
>   termination.
>
> Another class of problem is
>   characterised by a wide interface to
>   existing C code. A typical example is
>   implementing operating system device
>   drivers.
>
> Most (all?) large systems developed
>   using Erlang make heavy use of C for
>   low-level code, leaving Erlang to
>   manage the parts which tend to be
>   complex in other languages, like
>   controlling systems spread across
>   several machines and implementing
>   complex protocol logic.

As suggested by Andrzej, you should look into other directions. Maybe a different question on StackOverflow asking "which language would be good for..." could be the first step...

**UPDATE**

If you still intend to use Erlang to reset your passwords you might want to have a look to [the Erlang SSH Channel Behaviour](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh_channel.html) as well.

Reading from the doc:

> Ssh services are implemented as channels that are multiplexed over an ssh connection and
>   communicates via the ssh connection protocol. This module provides a callback API that
>   takes care of generic channel aspects such as flow control and close messages and lets the 
>   callback functions take care of the service specific parts.

Comment: Please see the comment above.

Comment: the FAQ saying it's not made for exactly that purpose is no indication of how appropriate a language is. the tools are there to solve it and the "not particularly suitable for" section doesn't even apply.

Comment: And the question is actually "how can I use Erlang for this...", not "should I use Erlang for this..."

Comment: Fair enough. This was just my opinion, emerged after using Erlang ssh for similar things and realizing that other alternatives could have worked as well in a simpler way. Mine was more a comment rather than a question, but it was too long to put it there :)